# SSJS script to update query and start automation with 3 minute wait in between each loop iteration

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ssjs, automationstudio

I have a script that have nested loops that loop through some arrays. In those loops, I have a something that updates a SQL Query Activity, then something to start an automation.

What I am trying to achieve is for there to be a few minutes between each loop iteration. My script works without `setTimeout()`. However, once I put my script around a function with `setTimeout()`, then an error occurs. Below is my SSJS:

```js
<script type = "text/javaScript" runat = "server" >
Platform.Load("core", "1.1.1");

var dataextensions = [
    "test4journey",
    "test4journey1"
];
var i;
var listids = [
    "1402390",
    "1423233"
];
var j;

(function theLoop(n) {
    setTimeout(function() {

        for (i = 0; i < dataextensions.length; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < listids.length; j++) {


                var QD_EligibleContent_ExternalKey = "289a3026-017b-4af7-92ad-690d17112433";
                var QD_EligibleContent = QueryDefinition.Init(QD_EligibleContent_ExternalKey);
                var qd_updatestatus = QD_EligibleContent.Update({
                    QueryText: "select ls.emailaddress as email \n from _ListSubscribers ls \n where \n ls.emailaddress = 'email@email.com'",
                    TargetUpdateType: "Overwrite",
                    Target: {
                        Name: dataextensions[i],
                        CustomerKey: dataextensions[i]
                    }
                });

                var automationCustomerKey = "b2d491dd-8f85-4e0c-92d7-05f9d88789a4"
                var api = new Script.Util.WSProxy();
                var action = "Start";
                api.setClientId({
                    "ID": '6275722'
                });
                var props = {
                    CustomerKey: 'b2d491dd-8f85-4e0c-92d7-05f9d88789a4'
                };
                var opts = {};
                var data = api.performItem("Automation", props, action, opts);

            }

        }

        if (--n) {
            theLoop(n);
        }
    }, 180000);
})(2);

</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can create your own wait function with for loop and a break. See my [blog post](https://gortonington.com/wait-function-for-ssjs-and-use-cases-for-it/) for more details.

Sample wait function:

```
<script runat=server> 
function sleep(milliseconds) { 
  var start = new Date().getTime(); 
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) { 
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break; 
    } 
  } 
} 

sleep(1000); //Wait for 1 second </script>
```